# Dynamically loading the size of a structure in C

Tags: c, shared-libraries

I have a file named Point.c which has a structure defined named as:

```
Point
```

Also, it has functions in it named point_str, point_deserialize.

Now, there are similar files like these like

```
LinkedList.c, Node.c etc with similar definitions.
```

Now, I am calling these functions dynamically in another file by using dlopen.

So, if I find that the type is Point, I will create a string:

```
point_str
```

and call the function by giving the path to the .so file using dlopen.

But, I am not able to know the size of the structure dynamically. Is there a way to do it? I want to do something like

```
int size = givemesize("Point", "path_to_so");
```

Which is just like dlopen but to know the size of a structure.

Edit: why I want to know the size?

With that size I am deserializing anything from string to its actual type. That's why I need the size. So, from command line it comes to deserialize a Point object. So, with that string I want to know the actual size of the Point object which resides in Point.c and has a libpoint.so

Comment: Isn't the struct defined in the header file?

Comment: If there isn't a header that defines the structure, then the interface in the library should provide a function (or, perish the thought, global variable) which you could access via `dlsym()` to get the value.  Or, more likely, it provides some APIs to allocate space for the structure for you.  Without support from the library (as header or runtime information), you'd have to write code loosely equivalent to a debugger to get at the information - if the library is compiled with debug symbols/information available.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, No it is in the same file. If I define it in the header file, suppose Point.h, how will that solve the problem?

Comment: If you need to know the size of a type that's behind opaque pointers, then I'd say something smells fishy (there's a high probability that you're using a wrong approach to solving a problem.) Could you edit the question and provide some information about why you need to know the size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot.

The .so doesn't know the size of the structure unless you encode it in a function available from the .so (like Jonathan said in the comments).  All that information is discarded at compile time.  Any relevant pointer/memory offsets are computed during compilation and the information used to compute those offsets is thrown away.

Comment: Thank you. I did it by adding a function in Point.o.